# Elasticsearch OR filtered query does not return results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data set:

```
{
    "_index": "myIndex",
    "_type": "myType",
    "_id": "220005",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "id": "220005",
        "name": "Some Name",
        "type": "myDataType",
        "doc_as_upsert": true
    }
}
```

Doing a direct match query like so:

```
GET typo3data/destination/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "Some Name"
        }
    },
    "size": 500
}
```

Will return the data just fine:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 3.442347,
    "hits": [...
```

Doing an OR-query however (I am not sure which syntax is correct, the first syntax is taken from elasticsearch docs, the second is a working query taken from another project with the same versions):

```
GET typo3data/destination/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "or": {
                    "filters": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "name": "Some Name"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 500
}
```

or

```
{
    "query":
    {
            "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter":
    {
            "or":
            [
                    { "term": { "name": "Some Name"} },
                    { "term": { "name": "Some Other Name"} }
            ]
    },
    "size": 1000
}
```

Does not return anything.

The mapping for the name field is:

```
"name": {
  "type": "string",
  "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

Elasticsearch version is 1.4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When indexing "some name" , this is broken into tokens as follows -

```
"some name" => [ "some" , "name" ]
```

Now in a normal match query , it also does the same above process before matching result. If either "same" or "name" is present , that document is qualified as result

```
 match query ("some name") => search for term "some" or  "name"
```

The term query does not analyze or tokenize your query. This means that it looks for a exact token or term of "some name" which is not present.

```
 term query ("some name") => search for term "some name"
```

Hence you wont be seeing any result.
Things should work fine if you make the field not_analyzed , but then make sure the case is also matching,
You can read more about the same [here](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-aggregation-custom-analyzer).

Comment: Ah...because term is looking for the **exact** phrase and match looks for fittings parts...
So match would be more fitting in this case, instead of term. However it won't let me put match as a keyword into the "or" array. Why can't I use "match" instead of "term" within "or"?

Comment: match is a query , not a filter. You can use normal bool query ( should section ) to get the or functanility or you will need to embed the match query inside query filter - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

After extending our mapping to include every field we have:

```
PUT typo3data/_mapping/destination
{
    "someType": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "parentId": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "generatedUid": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The or-filters were working. So the general answer is: If you have such a problem, check your mappings closely and rather do too much work on them than too little.

If someone has an explanation why this might be happening, I will gladly pass the answer mark on to it.